# Refactor npm request method code

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Currently using npm request, I want to refactor my code to the following:

```
app.post('/work_order',function (req,res) {
  var work_order = req.body.work_order;
  var url = soapURI + work_order;
  reqMethod(url);
});

app.get('/work_order/:work_order', function (req, res) {
  var work_order = req.params.work_order;
  var url = soapURI + work_order;
  reqMethod(url);
});

function reqMethod (url){
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      // console.log(body); // Print the json response
      res.send(body);
    }
  });
}
```

Problem is that `reqMethod` is now a promise, and `res.send(body)` is part of it. I couldn't simply `return res.send(body)`. I had 2 repetitive pieces of code (every of them is exactly like that of the method) sit in both `.get` and `.post` , so I want to move them out to a common, reusable method.

Questions:

1. How can I make it work?
2. Is `request` a good npm module? Can you suggest some alternatives and maybe, better ones?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options.

Option 1: Pass the result (res) parameter into the reqMethod:

```
app.post('/work_order',function (req,res) {
  var work_order = req.body.work_order;
  var url = soapURI + work_order;
  reqMethod(url, res);
});

app.get('/work_order/:work_order', function (req, res) {
  var work_order = req.params.work_order;
  var url = soapURI + work_order;
  reqMethod(url, res);
});
function reqMethod (url, res){
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      // console.log(body); // Print the json response
      res.send(body);
    }
    else {
      //send error here
    }
  });
}
```

Option 2: Add a callback to reqMethod

```
app.post('/work_order',function (req,res) {
  var work_order = req.body.work_order;
  var url = soapURI + work_order;
  reqMethod(url, function(err, body) {
    res.send(body)
  );
});

app.get('/work_order/:work_order', function (req, res) {
  var work_order = req.params.work_order;
  var url = soapURI + work_order;
  reqMethod(url, function(err, body) {
    res.send(body)
  );
});
function reqMethod (url, cb){
  request({
    url: url,
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
      // console.log(body); // Print the json response
      cb(null, body);
    }
    else {
      cb(error)
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer addressing the issues I have. That does really help me.

Answer (score 1):

The Express request handler needs to use `res.send()` in it's own scope or the required variables need to be passed along to your helper function so `res` can be used there.

Using [promises](https://promisesaplus.com/) allows for a simpler error handling flow when they are used as the basis of Express request handling (instead of callbacks).

The [Bluebird promise](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/) library provides a very useful superset of standard Promise functionality. [ES6 promises](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html) have been a part of native Node.js since 4.x

[Needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle) does everything HTTP that I've required so far and it's much, much, much lighter weight than `request`.

#### Code

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const needle = Promise.promisifyAll(require('needle'));

function expressResponse (req, res, next, promisedResponse) {
  return promisedResponse
    .then( (result) => res.send(result) )
    .catch( next );
}

function reqMethod (url) {
  return needle
    .getAsync( url, {json: true} )
    .then( (response) => {
      if ( response.statusCode !== 200 )
        throw new Error('Status '+response.statusCode);
      return response.body;
    });
}

app.get('/work_order', function (req, res, next) {
  let work_order = req.body.work_order;
  let url = soapURI + work_order;
  expressResponse( req, res, next, reqMethod(url) );
});

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send(err.message)
})
```

`expressResponse()` keeps the Express components seperate from any response generation code in case I want to use those functions for something other than express.

`reqMethod()` returns a promise from a [Bluebird promisified](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promisification.html) `needle.getAsync()` which calls `needle.get()` and automagically converts the callback into a promise for you.

A `next` has been added to the Express request handler method signature and that is also passed to `expressResponse()`. Then `.catch(next)` is attached to the promise chain.  This will allow Express to handle any uncaught exceptions thrown by a promise.

The use of `next()` error handling requires the addition of an [Express error handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.error-handling). You can make this a lot more `Error` aware, producing different responses for different `Error` classes.

Note that with Promises you can now `throw` normal exceptions safely in an asynchronous Promise like in `reqMethod()` and they will be handled by the Express error middleware.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I appreate it greatly as I saw Bluebird and I viewed it through Sequelize docs. Yes, I wanted to check on how Bluebird promise is. You reply has enlightened me on both Bluebird and needle (with needle being a good alternative to request). Will definitely test it. Thanks,